# Why can't I send an XHR request with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm new to Apache Cordova and i've heard that it's the simplest way to develop android apps. So I did everything okay (or at least I believe so), but I can not get XHR request on my app. Both mobile & TV shows the same thing, while emulators like bluestacks showing the desired result.

What I see (big screen - android tv, small screen - my mobile):
[image]

I expect to see whatever my server returns.

This is my code (HTML: `<div id="i" style="font-size:20px;line-height:auto;">Please wait while we initialize the app...</div>`; index.js on cordova):

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Cordova is now initialized. Have fun!
    
    var __domain = 'http://192.168.1.100/android-app/';
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', __domain + '.cordova.request.allow.php', 1);
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML += '<br>Preparing requested files...';
        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML += '<br>ReadyState on ' + this.readyState + ' and Status returned ' + this.status;
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 && this.response == 1) {
            // It's okay
            // Append init
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = __domain + 'init.js';
            
            // Force load this script
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        }
    }, 0);
    xhr.send();
}
```

PHP file should return "1" (as string - the file contents: `<?php echo 1; return;`), and this is init.js:

```
document.body.style.background = 'blue';
document.body.style.color = 'white';
alert('success');
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I dynamically get data from server with XHR?

Both mobile & tv connected to the same network using WiFi

(using xiaomi mi box for tv and xiaomi redmi mobile)

Update - for @CedricCholley:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data: content:;">
```

Comment: Has your domain (`__domain`) have been added to the `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag ?

Comment: @CedricCholley I'm not sure, i'll update my Content-Security-Policy tag here so you can see; Updated

Comment: It looks like [`connect-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) is missing. try to add `connect-src: http://192.168.1.100/android-app/` in the content attribute of that meta tag

Comment: I've added: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data: content: connect-src: http://192.168.1.100/android-app/;">` - Still the same

Comment: Not sure this is the reason but you have an extra `content`. Try this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data: connect-src: http://192.168.1.100">`

Comment: @CedricCholley on mobile still not working :(

Comment: ^ update: on tv not working too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222495/discussion-between-cedric-cholley-and-user11247237).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the help of @CedricCholley. I connected the app to chrome console (with the guide here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/48/how-to-debug-a-cordova-app-on-your-device-with-google-chrome) and got the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`. after googling i've found out that this is happening because the app has no permission to access the internet, so i've followed this guide also: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova/connection/connection.html

added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

to `platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`